# Prompt has been changed after upgrade to 18.04.1 after using "su" to change user

Tags: command-line, bash, su, auto-completion

Just updated to 18.04.1  I use Terminal only.  When I do an su to one my users that runs a game, I only get a    $   and no name of the user and does not show current location.  Also, tab autocomplete will not work for those users either.  I can still navigate just fine if I manually type everything.  Tab auto complete works for my regular user as well as root.

Comment: What if you try `su - username` ?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the output of `getent passwd username | cut -f7 -d:`? also `which bash`?

Comment: I get no output from getent passwd username | cut -f7 -d:   And which bash says /bin/bash

Comment: you have to place your username instead of `username`, ex: `getent passwd ravexina | cut -f7 -d:`

Comment: Just an empty space shows up.  The two users in question are not able to be logged in to with a password.  Can only su to them.

Comment: Use this: `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash [your-username]` then use `su - your-username` to check if problem has been solved.

Comment: That resolved it!  Thank you very much!  I wonder why the update altered their bash choice.

Comment: Have no idea, I will sent it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
getent passwd username | cut -f7 -d:
```

if you get an empty result it means your user does not have a default shell thus it is using `/bin/sh` by default. And that is why it looks like what you are describing.

Run:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash username
```

to fix the issue